# Incorrect RTL rendering of Arabic numbers in enumerate

Tags: polyglossia

I have the following code in latex to write in both Arabic and English:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale=maghrib, numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=1, Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\altarabicfont[Script=Arabic]{KacstFarsi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Temp}
This is a temporary chapter. Number 256.

\section{Section A}
Here is the first section. We want to start writing in Arabic:

    \begin{Arabic}
نريد أن نكتب بالعربية رقم ٢٥٦ أو 256
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item هذا هو الرقم الأول256 
        \item هذا هو الرقم الثاني ١٥٥
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

I have 2 problems:

1. The rendering of enumerate is incorrect.
2. All numbers in the Arabic text wherever used appear inverted, for example 256 is rendered 652.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

[image]

Comment: There is no locale called `maghrib`, did you mean `mashriq`? I do not have the font `Traditional Arabic` installed, I tested your code with `Amiri` and got what I believe to be the correct result. Could you provide your .log file?

Comment: It is strange. I still get the same results even with Amiri font and mashriq locale.. Here is my log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tWFMgRXkzpSISb33ppjppN5c_H2fmuqe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I even tried compiling the same code on overleaf, I get the same errors..

Comment: Oh, I see. You are compiling with `LuaTeX`. When the text direction is right to left in `LuaTeX`, numbers will be typeset right to left as well. In this case polyglossia is loading a package called `luabidi` to support RTL typesetting, but this package is not really maintained, and is kind of broken. Either use `XeTeX` as the underlying engine,  or use `babel` instead of polygossia.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will switch to babel then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to solve this problem is by switching to babel, which I found to be less headache than this..