# Number direction in Arabic using (plain) Luatex

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, arabic, optex

Following the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442855/arabic-right-to-left-using-luatex), I managed to write in Arabic using Luatex (plain/Optex), but all numbers are also written from the right to the left (and in Western numbers, not Arabic). It seems that the [Luabidi package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689675/incorrect-rtl-rendering-of-arabic-numbers-in-enumerate) also has the same issue.

Is there a way to selectively activate left-to-right + correct "font" selection for numbers in this case?

```
\font\dubai={Dubai:script=arabic} at 12pt

\def\setArabic{\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT}
\def\setLatin {\pagedir TLT \bodydir TLT \pardir TLT \textdir TLT}

\def\arabe#1{
\bgroup 
\setArabic\dubai #1
\egroup
}

\arabe{ دبي هي المدينة الأكثر اكتظاظاً بالسكان في الإمارات  0123456 ٢٥٦ العربية المتحدة.}

\bye
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very basic OpTeX solution:

```tex
\ufont\plexarabic={file:ibmplexsansarabic-regular.otf:script=arabic} at 12pt

\def\arabe#1{{
    \pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT
    \plexarabic #1
}}

\directlua{
    % Add any characters here that you want to always be LTR
    local chars = {
        "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"
    }

    local _chars = {}
    for i, char in ipairs(chars) do
        _chars[utf8.codepoint(char)] = true
    end

    local insert_before = node.insert_before
    local copy = node.copy
    local fonts = font.fonts

    local push_dir = node.new("dir")
    push_dir.dir = "+TLT"
    local pop_dir = node.new("dir")
    pop_dir.dir = "-TLT"

    callback.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", function (head)
        local found = false
        for n, char, font in node.traverse_glyph(head) do
            char = fonts[font].characters[char].unicode
            if not found and _chars[char] then
                found = true
                head = insert_before(head, n, copy(push_dir))
            elseif found then
                if not _chars[char] then
                    found = false
                    head = insert_before(head, n, copy(pop_dir))
                end
            end
        end

        return head
    end, "test")
}

\arabe{ دبي هي المدينة الأكثر اكتظاظاً بالسكان في الإمارات  0123456 ٢٥٦ العربية المتحدة.}

\bye
```

[image]

True bidi is a really hard problem; if you want a complete/robust solution, you'll likely need to switch to LaTeX or ConTeXt.

Comment: Hindi (Arabic) numbers are still in the wrong order, but it works great for "Arabic" (Western) numbers. Yes, you're right Xetex does it, and maybe Context,

Comment: @user574859 Ah, okay. I think that's fixed in the edit? I have no idea which characters should always be LTR and which should be RTL, but it should be pretty easy to modify this by adding characters to the `chars` Lua table.

Comment: I guess that's all that is need for most things. Very straightforward. Thank you so much.